# SwiftUI Map updates from the 2nd time

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swiftui

I've stuck with a problem that my Map updates only from the 2nd try.
So let me describe in detail:

0. Here's my app's interface: [image]
1. As u can see, there's the horizontal top bar with cards. On tap of each, the list of toggles below updates from the CoreData. Each area has its location. What I want to do is to show the location of each on that small map.
2. Here's the code of my Map [image]
3. I have the $homeRegion state variable on top of my struct, then it's being updated with this func that's being called on the area card click.[image]
4. So basically I'm updating the $homeRegion var when switching the card. Everything seems to be ok, print prints right coordinates, the pin appears in the right place, but the map doesn't move there. But, when I tap for the 2nd time, the map moves there. If I have 3 cards and will go like 1st, 2nd, 3rd, the pin will apply on the 3rd one (the latest I've tapped), but the map gonna move to the 2nd place.

Hope I was clear, if smth, I'm also open to giving more info. But I'm just stuck on getting the map updated from the 1st time)

Thanks for the help and for your patience

Piece <3

Upd:
Passing code here as well:

`private func setCurrentLocation() { homeRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: selectedArea.first?.areaLatitude ?? 0.0, longitude: selectedArea.first?.areaLongitude ?? 0.0), latitudinalMeters: 500, longitudinalMeters: 500) print(" HOME REGION \n", homeRegion) }`

`Map(coordinateRegion: $homeRegion, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: nil, annotationItems: [newAreaVM.pinHere]) { place in MapPin(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: selectedArea.first?.areaLatitude ?? 0.0, longitude: selectedArea.first?.areaLongitude ?? 0.0)) } .cornerRadius(16) .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 200, maxHeight: 280, alignment: .center) .overlay( RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16) .stroke(Color("Border"), lineWidth: 1) )`

Comment: Please include code, not images of code, which can't be searched, copied/pasted, or read by screen readers.

Comment: @jnpdx added the code below. Sry for inconvenience

Comment: Have you found any solution?